# How to make correlation matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, correlation

I'm trying to make a correlation matrix of some data I have given in an array below:

```
y35=np.array([[  9.04000000e-02,   9.04000000e-02,   9.04000000e-02,
      9.04000000e-02,   9.04000000e-02,   9.04000000e-02,
      9.04000000e-02,   9.04000000e-02,   9.04000000e-02,
      9.04000000e-02],
   [  9.46800000e-01,   9.46800000e-01,   9.46800000e-01,
      9.46800000e-01,   9.46800000e-01,   9.46800000e-01,
      9.46800000e-01,   9.46800000e-01,   9.46800000e-01,
      9.46800000e-01],
   [  6.80272109e-01,   6.80272109e-01,   6.80272109e-01,
      6.80272109e-01,   6.80272109e-01,   6.80272109e-01,
      6.80272109e-01,   6.80272109e-01,   6.80272109e-01,
      6.80272109e-01],
   [  5.55695613e+00,   4.40457792e+00,   2.58692265e+00,
      3.10252325e+00,   1.85659725e+00,   1.58770175e+00,
      1.27029193e+00,   1.22547602e+00,   6.24159540e-01,
      3.28069915e-01],
   [  1.22542004e-01,   1.19660646e-01,   1.15375709e-01,
      1.00806250e-01,   9.82258281e-02,   1.22255123e-01,
      1.11509245e-01,   9.63047089e-02,   9.49071249e-02,
      1.07669297e-01],
   [  1.72782585e+02,   1.74085379e+02,   1.74116403e+02,
      1.75804574e+02,   1.78202635e+02,   1.74750785e+02,
      1.73381976e+02,   1.78039625e+02,   1.76411576e+02,
      1.74783584e+02],
   [  1.13554778e+01,   1.09463219e+01,   9.83468822e+00,
      1.00570149e+01,   9.34893234e+00,   9.30782992e+00,
      9.03692761e+00,   8.96780081e+00,   8.64084974e+00,
      8.29334746e+00]])
```

I the dimension is (7,10) and I want the correlation between the 7 rows. I have seen the method y35.corr() which seems to give what I want but I don't know where to "put" my my data so that I can use the .corr() method.

Comment: corr method exists in pandas.DataFrame : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html
numpy has 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html
and
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html
I am not sure which you need.

Comment: Question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657433/correlation-matrix-in-python