# How to make a correlation matrix using npcorrcoef between 2 columns in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-science

I want to see if there is a relationship between two columns: low_wage_jobs and unemployment_rate, so I'm trying to create a correlation matrix of a numpy array: recent_grads_np. Can someone show me how it is done? I have been trying to find and read the documentation of this and yet still don't really get it.

here is a look at the array:

```
array([[   37,   193],
       [   85,    50],
       [   16,     0],
       [   40,     0],
       [ 1672,   972],
       [  400,   244],
       [  308,   259],
       [   33,   220],
       [ 4650,  3253],
       [ 3895,  3170],
       [ 2275,   980],
       [  794,   372],
       [ 1019,   789],
       [   78,    81],
       [   23,   263],
       [  589,   524],
       [  699,   640],
       [ 2859,  3192],
       [  170,   137],
       [   11,   144],
       [ 6884,  5144],
       [  338,   485],
       [  824,   696],
       [   70,    70],
       [ 1015,   708],
       [ 3270,  2899],
       [ 1042,   703],
       [  504,   285],
       [  597,   365],
       [  670,   340],
       [  308,   260],
       [  163,   142],
       [  286,   755],
       [   49,    49],
       [ 8497,  6193],
       [ 9413,  9910],
       [11452, 10653],
       [ 1165,  1284],
       [  129,   480],
       [  137,   124],
       [12411, 10886],
       [ 2884,  4569],
       [ 2934,  1672],
       [ 1282,  1823],
       [  505,  1002],
       [  639,   608],
       [  401,   343],
       [  385,   357],
       [  107,    93],
       [   99,   186],
       [   74,   245],
       [  407,  1270],
       [    0,    25],
       [  419,   263],
       [  223,   135],
       [   88,     0],
       [ 2271,  2499],
       [14946, 27320],
       [ 4366,  4221],
       [ 2092,  3046],
       [  977,  1121],
       [ 1067,  1168],
       [ 1150,  1758],
       [  649,  1362],
       [  178,   839],
       [  416,   386],
       [  250,   406],
       [   87,   201],
       [  215,   573],
       [  138,   302],
       [  286,   272],
       [  182,    94],
       [   42,   269],
       [    0,     0],
       [ 2769,  4288],
       [   64,    81],
       [21502, 32395],
       [11663, 27968],
       [15022, 19803],
       [ 1799,  1905],
       [  693,  1246],
       [  721,   308],
       [ 2249,  3012],
       [    0,    56],
       [ 1100,   352],
       [  677,   959],
       [ 1315,  1906],
       [  757,  1336],
       [  893,  1422],
       [  789,   496],
       [   36,   221],
       [   33,    37],
       [ 1779,  3175],
       [14602, 27440],
       [11268, 18404],
       [ 8947, 14839],
       [ 4535,  8512],
       [ 2727,  5751],
       [ 3305,  7214],
       [ 1668,  3677],
       [ 1067,  1179],
       [ 1088,  2237],
       [ 1743,  1895],
       [  975,  2449],
       [ 1518,  1391],
       [ 2006,  2495],
       [  962,   557],
       [  842,  1405],
       [  463,   902],
       [  749,  1061],
       [   78,   237],
       [  322,   327],
       [    0,     0],
       [ 7195, 11443],
       [11176, 16839],
       [ 3132,  5267],
       [ 1718,  3168],
       [ 1012,  1806],
       [ 1833,  1854],
       [  216,   786],
       [    0,   111],
       [  529,  1159],
       [  483,   459],
       [13874, 28339],
       [ 8608, 13748],
       [ 4410,  6429],
       [ 2409,  4468],
       [ 2393,  9063],
       [ 1379,  2819],
       [ 1302,  2085],
       [  547,   657],
       [  757,  1470],
       [  437,   976],
       [  833,  1385],
       [ 2183,  3816],
       [ 4267,  8051],
       [ 1206,  2767],
       [14345, 26503],
       [ 7297, 11502],
       [ 5593, 16838],
       [ 4657,  9030],
       [ 3718,  5862],
       [ 1108,  1634],
       [  314,  1231],
       [  266,   591],
       [28169, 48207],
       [ 3918,  9286],
       [ 1920,  2042],
       [ 1128,  3426],
       [ 5486, 11880],
       [ 3355,  5248],
       [ 3329,  4344],
       [  917,  2125],
       [ 1465,  2840],
       [  496,   722],
       [  419,  1650],
       [  326,   724],
       [  372,  1141],
       [ 1617,  3304],
       [ 1368,  3586],
       [  510,  3163],
       [   82,    31],
       [ 3395,  6866],
       [ 1487,  5125],
       [ 1360,  2868],
       [  846,  1115],
       [ 3040, 11068],
       [ 1340,  3466],
       [  304,   743],
       [  148,    82],
       [  368,   622],
       [  214,   308],
       [   87,   192]])
```

note: recent_grads_np is a numpy array that has been created through a conversion of dataframe named recent_grads.

Comment: You may find useful answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657433/correlation-matrix-in-python .

Answer (score 0):

if your array is `foo`, then:

```
np.corrcoeff(foo.T)[0, 1]
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

Correlation can be found very easily with **pandas** like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['low_wage_jobs', 'unemployment_rate'])
df.corr()
```

And if you are experimenting with **numpy**, try like this:

```
import numpy as np
np.corrcoef(list(df['low_wage_jobs']), list(df['unemployment_rate']))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: is it possible to do it only with the numpy array recent_grads_np?

Comment: Not sure if you can use that numpy array directly. But you can definitely try to split that array into 2 different arrays and use the above numpy method.